# UI Objects & ProgressBar - Not Updating AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hi guys added all the code I could below in regards to my problem. Note that both the Progress bar and the text view are NOT UPDATING via asynctask. The textview can be edited in getview method but not the progressbar as when I try to set to 40 it doesn't update the ui as 40.

Code Below is commeneted please read comments! I've tried a lot of different ways but I am still stuck here

Both textview and ProgressBar are not updating via (onprogressupdated) the asyncTask at the moment.

Here is the reference to official android doc as comparison code: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Here is another stackoverflow question I looked at: 
[Android Async Task Progress Bar onProgressUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232343/android-async-task-progress-bar-onprogressupdate)

```
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
        if (!(data.get(position) instanceof TemporarySongInfomation)) {
            SongViewHolder holder;
            if(view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_list_format, null);
                holder = new SongViewHolder();
                holder.timesplayed = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                holder.artist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                holder.imagebutton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
                holder.source = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            } else holder = (SongViewHolder)view.getTag();
            tempValue = (SongInfomation) data.get(position);
            String songName = tempValue.getName();
            holder.imagebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbutton1);
            holder.source.setText(tempValue.getVideoid());
            holder.title.setText(songName.length() > 45 ? songName.substring(0, 38) + "..." : songName);
            holder.timesplayed.setText("" + tempValue.getTimesplayed());
            holder.artist.setText(tempValue.getArtist());
            swipeDetector = new SwipeDetector();
            view.setOnClickListener(new SongListOnItemClickListener(position));
            view.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);
            holder.imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnPlayButtonClickListener(position));
        } else {
            TemporarySongViewHolder holder = new TemporarySongViewHolder();

            if(view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_list_process_format, null);
                holder.artist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artisttemp);
                holder.bar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
                holder.textpercent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
                holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titletemp);
                holder.source = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sourcetemp);
            } else holder = (TemporarySongViewHolder) view.getTag();
            tempValue1 = (TemporarySongInfomation) data.get(position);
            String songName = tempValue1.getName();
            holder.source.setText(tempValue1.getVideoid());
            holder.title.setText(songName.length() > 45 ? songName.substring(0, 38) + "..." : songName);
            holder.artist.setText(tempValue1.getArtist());
            holder.textpercent.setText("Initializing");
            new UpdateProgressBar(holder.bar, tempValue1, holder.textpercent).execute();

    }

    return view;
}



 class UpdateProgressBar extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
     TemporarySongInfomation songinfo;
     ProgressBar progress;
    TextView textpercent;

    UpdateProgressBar(ProgressBar bar, TemporarySongInfomation tp, TextView percent) {
        progress = bar;
        songinfo = tp;
        textpercent = percent;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (!songinfo.isCompleted()) {
            publishProgress((int) songinfo.getProgress());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        System.out.println("progress: "+values[0]);
        progress.setProgress(values[0]);
        textpercent.setText("Current Progress: "+values[0] + "%");
    }
}
```

XML as needed also commented please read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/titletemp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/artisttemp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titletemp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/sourcetemp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/artisttemp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sourcetemp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar2" />
```

As Requested:

```
 class SongViewHolder {
    TextView title, artist, timesplayed, source;
    ImageButton imagebutton;
}

class TemporarySongViewHolder {
    TextView title, artist, source, textpercent;
    ProgressBar bar;
}
```

Comment: is it entering into while loop ?

Comment: yes but according to the android docs publishProgress can occur inside a loop for example if you look they use a forloop

Comment: no i am asking you when you run it enters inside ?

Comment: Yes in my comments it says what is printing from the loop.

Comment: @YaWang : In your adapter's `getView(...)` method you're not checking to see if `convertView` is null or not and creating a new `View` and holder regardless. You're also not setting the tag of the `View` to be the holder `Object`. Both of these defeat the point of having `conVertView` and using the holder pattern. Fix those issues first then update your question.

Comment: @Squonk Thanks I listened and checked for a null so that the getView doesn't repeat to cause 2 instances of async task. Posted update able but the text now updates "current progress %" but the progressbar is still a spinning circle

Comment: @YaWang : As far as I understand it `progressBarStyleSmall` is always a spinning wheel and always indeterminate so you'r unable to set its progress value.

Comment: @YaWang : Also, you're still not setting the holder as the tag for the `View` and don't have code to retreive the holder if `convertView` is not null.

Comment: @Squonk ok take a look now, still same deal changed progress bar to normal, also used tags everything works except progress bar still jsut white circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was looking for a horizontal progress bar...

In addition, should use getTag() to prevent double calling of getview